# Не могу получить первый элемента массива из массива объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы

У меня есть массив объектов. Вот так он выглядит в консоле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить первый элемент массива из массива объектов?

Я пытался сделать вот так, но он вывел undefined:

```html
arrayOfObjects[0]
```

Примерно такой код:

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
var arr = [];
$.ajax({
  url: root + '/posts',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
  arr.push(data[0]);
});
function func() {
 console.log(arr[0])
}
setTimeout(func, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<телепатия>`

Вы пытаетесь получить первый элемент из массива раньше, чем Ваш код заполняет этот массив данными.

`</телепатия>`

Спасибо за внимание! Наши представления - каждый четверг.

*Update*

Новая информация:

[Необычное поведение javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762920)

Вы запрашиваете данные для массива асинхронно. А первый элемент выводите сразу, не дожидаясь возвращения асинхронного запроса. В консоли же Вы наблюдаете массив после заполнения его данными - консоль хранит на него ссылку и обновляется, отражая изменения в массиве/объекте.

@selya: Чтобы посмотреть, что было в массиве в самом начале, выводите не сам массив, а `JSON.stringify(arr)`, к примеру.

Comment: Почему тут нельзя ставить больше плюсов? Даже репутацией готов пожертвовать за такой ответ :)

Comment: @Klimenkomud репутацией можно (конкурсом).

Comment: Большое Вам Спасибо!

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Но если ответ уже принят - то нельзя :(

Comment: Ну шаман, ну силен.. Из шоу экстрасенсов наверное с мобилы зашел