# Необычное поведение javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Добрый день! У меня есть массив который загружается с базы данных. Если после загрузки массива отобразить его в консоль, то он без проблем отобразится. `console.log(arr)` Но, если вывести его первый элемент `console.log(arr[0])`, то в консоли отобразится 
`undefined`
. Я попробовал этот элемент вывести через 3 секунды после загрузки страницы. `setTimeout('console.log(arr[0])', 3000)`. Все без проблем сработало. Можете пожалуйста объяснить это явление.

Вот код:

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
var arr = [];
$.ajax({
  url: root + '/posts',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
  arr.push(data[0]);
});
function func() {
 console.log(arr[0])
}
setTimeout(func, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Покажите код, мы не телепаты )

Comment: Suvitruf, Этот вопрос возник у меня давно. И я закончил свой проект с костылем )). Кода к сожелению нет(

Comment: Тогда и помочь вам никто ничем не может. `у меня есть массив` - тогда уже _был_)

Comment: Нет, не можем. Нужен конкретный код и конкретный пример. Ответить на вопрос в таком виде нет никакой возможности, легче погадать вам по фотографии вашей тещи.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751888 - так Вы не поняли, в чем там было дело?

Comment: @wirtwelt - Вы удивитесь, но я уже ответил на этот вопрос месяц назад

Comment: @Igor Да, увидел. Мое почтение, магистр ))

Comment: @Igor, Я хочу понять, почему это происходит.

Comment: @YernarSadybekov Мне, видимо, следовало объяснить этот "загадочный" феномен более подробно. Сейчас.

Comment: @YernarSadybekov Вы, скорее всего, запрашиваете данные для массива асинхронно. А первый элемент выводите сразу, не дожидаясь возвращения асинхронного запроса. В консоли же Вы наблюдаете массиве после заполнения его данными - консоль хранит на него ссылку и обновляется, отражая изменения в массиве/объекте.

Comment: @Igor Дополню. Чтобы посмотреть, что было в массиве в самом начале, выводите не сам массив, а `JSON.stringify(arr)`, к примеру

Comment: @Igor Напишите тогда уже развернутый ответ, раз в вопросе появился код)

Comment: @YernarSadybekov Ваша дополнительная информация про три секунды укладывается в эту схему.

Comment: @YernarSadybekov - Добавьте, пожалуйста, код и дополнительную информацию в Ваш старый вопрос.

Comment: @selya - я добавил объяснение в старый вопрос. Мне надо было не выпендриваться, а сделать это месяц назад.